# Python syntax highlighting for php using pygments

Tags: python, text, syntax, highlighting

Can anyone explained me how to use pygments in python text widget? I want to make a syntax highlighting on every key press.

Comment: Pygment doc: [Quickstart](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/). You need text widget which render HTML.

Comment: btw: what python widget ? What framework do you use ?